# Dagger 2 not injecting sharedPreference

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

Hi i am new to dagger 2 and trying to inject an instance of sharedPreference inside my MyActivity class below:

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic lateinit var applicationComponent : ApplicationComponent
    }



    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().androidModule(AndroidModule(this)).build()

    }
}
```

Here is the component and modules

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AndroidModule::class))
interface ApplicationComponent {
    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
}

@Module
class AndroidModule (private val application: Application){ 

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplicationContext() : Context = application

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSharedPreference() : SharedPreferences = application.getSharedPreferences("shared pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

}


class MainActivity: Activity{
    @Inject
    internal lateinit var sharedPreference: SharedPreferences

    @Inject
    internal lateinit var MainScreenPresenter: MainScreenContract.Presenter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_Screen)
        MyApplication.applicationComponent.inject(this)

        sharedPreference.toString()

        initiateViews()
    }

}
```

I get the error below:

```
Error:(7, 1) error: android.content.SharedPreferences cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
```

Comment: `fun inject(any: Any)` You're going to have to be concrete. That's `fun inject(app: MyApplication)`.

Comment: what if i want to inject other kotlin classes? i want to be able to inject any class in the project that needs dependency injection

Comment: That's not how DI works. Philosophically it's about making concious decisions. Something along the lines of "yes, I am aware that this component can inject into this class". Technically the component needs a list of classes it's going to inject. Those classes are definitely going to be end consumers such as activities or application, something that's created for you by Android, and you inject it after it's been created. Other than that you'll use @Inject annotated constructors. Follow the official user guide.

Comment: So if I have created a class called Myclass I simply need to edit the component and add fun inject(myclass : Myclass )?

Comment: You only need to manually inject classes where you yourself don't call a constructor, such as Activity. If you created a class called `Myclass` you'd typically use constructor injection to inject its fields. Read here: https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide Then to obtain an instance you'd 1) declare property `@Inject lateinit var myclass: MyClass` in an Activity or Application (or other class instantiated by Android) so it can be injected 2) again use constructor injection.

Comment: Ok so i tried your suggestion and still it wont detect the sharedPreferences. i tried it on an activity instead of a Application class and no joy, it cant find sharedPreference. will update the question

Comment: This looks very much correct... Try clean & rebuild.

Comment: i fixed it by adding the mainClass inject type on the other component i created. it seems you need to add it to each component i make if the activity uses MyClassA that inside uses MyClassB injection.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have done it a little bit incorrect. First of all now there is dagger-android that helps with the problem of principle that solves the problem that components (such as Activities) should not know about how the injection happens.

you can read it here: https://medium.com/@iammert/new-android-injector-with-dagger-2-part-1-8baa60152abe

Just to be sure that dagger dependencies are in the Android project:

```
android {
     kapt {
        generateStubs = true
    }
}

compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13"
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.13"
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.13"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.13"
```

Your mistake is that you didn't tell to your graph that you want to make injections into the MainActivity. In the best way you should create `Subcomponent` for MainActivity, connect it with another Module for MainActivity that have injections that you want to inject into the MainActivity, set in your AppComponent the connection with Subcomponent and only than in MainAcitivy onCreate() method inject your dependency graph. But with dagger-android everything is easier.

Here is the code:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    ActivityBindingModule::class,
    AppModule::class
])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication> {

    fun inject(application: MyApplication)

    override fun inject(instance: DaggerApplication)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance fun application(application: MyApplication): Builder
        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

**AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class** : This goes from the dagger.android.support library. And it provides Android components (Activities/Fragments/Services/BroadcastReceiver/ContentProvider) with our module.

**@Component.Builder** in dagger2.10 provides us better way to create a builder of DaggerAppComponent.

**@BindsInstance** in the Builder will automatically create an instance of `MyApplication` so in `AppModule` we don't need to instantiate with MyApplication. It is already a dependency in the graph.

**ActivityBindingModule.clas** is our. I will tell about it later.

You can read more about this part here: https://proandroiddev.com/dagger-2-component-builder-1f2b91237856

Next is AppModule.class :

```
@Module
abstract class AppModule{

    @Binds
    abstract fun provideContext(application: MyApplication) : Context

    @Module
    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        @Provides
        fun provideSharedPreferences(context: Context): SharedPreferences =
            context.getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }
}
```

**@Binds** annotation replaces `@Provides` annotation and it just returns the value in the function parameter. As you see an instance of MyApplication is already in the graph and there is no need to inject MyApplication in the AppModule constructor.

NOTE: function with @Binds annotation should be abstract, and if there are function with @Provides annotation they should be `static`. 
The solution in Kotlin for static funcitons you can find here: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/900

**ActivityBindingModule.class:**

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainActivityModule::class])
    internal abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

With the **ActivityBindingModule** class we just create separate Module that will create **Subcomponents** for Android components for us.

More about ContributesAndroidInjector and Binds you can read here:
https://proandroiddev.com/dagger-2-annotations-binds-contributesandroidinjector-a09e6a57758f

**MainActivityModule.class:**

```
@Module
abstract class MainActivityModule {

    @Binds
    internal abstract fun provideMainActivity(activity: MainActivity): MainActivity
}
```

**MyApplication.class:**

```
class MyApplication: DaggerApplication(){

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        val appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .application(this)
            .build()
        appComponent.inject(this)
        return appComponent
    }
}
```

Do not forget insert Application in the Mainfest file.

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
...
>
    ...
</application>
```

For your Application class you need to implement DaggerApplication that implements HasActivityInjector/HasFragmentInjector/etc as well as call AndroidInjection.inject().

About this you can read more here : https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html

**MainActivity.class:**

```
class MainActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Log.d("TAAAAG", sharedPreferences.toString())
    }
}
```

As you can see `MainActivity` now does not know how SharedPreferences are injected. Actually there is `AndroidInjection.inject(this);` in the DaggerAppCompatActivity. If you don't extend you class from this, than you need to specify it in onCreate method by yourself, otherwise no injections will be done.

**EDIT:** 
You can check the code from GitHub: https://github.com/Belka1000867/Dagger2Kotlin

Comment: Wow this is nice. I'll give this a proper look. One thing I hate about Dagger is that you can't create a base activity that does this injection and just extend it and all the inject modules and components defined in the base activity

Comment: So i just checked out your examples below and got a question. Do i need to create a ActivityModule for each activity i use? Seems more of a hassle then to simply add that activity as a new inject method in the component?

Is there a way to just use a base activity or class to do all the injections?

Comment: Actually it is not such a big hassle with this kind of a solution. I also though like this when I only started with Dagger. But latter I came up with the conclusion that in every Module for each Activity you will need to specify different instances and for better use of Dagger it will be important to use Scopes for each function you provide in the graph. Here you can read about scopes: http://frogermcs.github.io/building-userscope-with-dagger2/

Comment: And actually there are also such classes DaggerApplication, DaggerAppCompatActivity, DaggerFragment and some others that simplifies the process of injection

Comment: I have done a github project for better view. https://github.com/Belka1000867/Dagger2Kotlin

Comment: ahh thanks! i will check this out. You have been of great help!

Comment: After carefully analysing your code and applying the same workflow on my project, i get a IllegalStateException saying that one of my bindings is not resoved for BindingKey(my view callback presenter). i then tried to remove the scoped @Singleton i had on the binding in question from the  module and it then explains that i cannot reference a scoped binding from an unscoped subComponent

Comment: If I understand correctly you had an @Singleton scope in the subcomponent, right? But singletons better to create in the Application module, so it will not be destroyed. And the scope can be only one for each component you provide. And about components there is a good article http://frogermcs.github.io/building-userscope-with-dagger2/ .

Comment: Yes that was issue. i changed the scope of the acitity layer modules and dependencies to a custom one. That did the trick

Comment: Update. so when i tried using a Fragment instead of an activity, this approach did not seem to inject the variables using same approach as doing it with activities using ActivityBindingModule

Comment: Do you use DaggerSupportFragment as super class of your fragment? Also check in that project on github I am using injection for fragments.

Comment: The problem and solution clearly indicates why Dagger is a piece of garbage that should never have been introduced into Android to start with. An overly complex piece of crap - and for what - unit testing?? lol. Just use a damn tool that mocks out classes when testing.

Comment: Works for me by simply adding  
val appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .application(this)
            .build()
        appComponent.inject(this)