# Having problem in injecting SharedPreference class using Dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I'm new to Dagger concepts, I've understood some extent I guess but keep having issues with injecting classes. I went through a lot of tutorials and sample codes but end up having an error when I have to multiple modules using a component and it mostly ends up with the shared preference module not being injected. Not able to understand the actual error or the mistake I'm making, need some assistance.

My Component class:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {VehicleModule.class, AppPreference.class})
public interface AppComponent {
//    void injectPreference(MainActivity activity);

 void inject(MainActivity activity);
 Vehicle provideVehicle();
}
```

My Shared Preference class:

```
@Module
public class AppPreference {
private SharedPreferences preferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor edit;

@ApplicationScope
@Provides
@Inject
public SharedPreferences getPreferences() {
    return preferences;
}

public AppPreference(Context context) {
//        preferences       =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    preferences     =   context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);
    edit            =   preferences.edit();
}

@Singleton
@Provides
public String setDataPref(String strKey, String strValue) {
    edit.putString(strKey, strValue);
    commitPreference();
    return strKey;
}

@Singleton
@Provides
public String removeFromPreference(String strKey) {
    edit.remove(strKey);
    return strKey;
}

public void commitPreference()
{
    edit.commit();
}

@Singleton
@Provides
public String getDataPref(String strKey) {
    return preferences.getString(strKey, "");
}

@Singleton
@Provides
public boolean clear() {
    edit.clear();
    commitPreference();

    return true;
}
}
```

My Application Class:

```
public class AppInstance extends Application {

AppComponent component;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    component = DaggerAppComponent.builder().appPreference(new AppPreference(getApplicationContext())).build();
}

public AppComponent getComponent() {
    return component;
}
}
```

Finally my Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 //    @Inject
 //    AppPreference preference;

private AppComponent appComponent;
Vehicle vehicle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().vehicleModule(new VehicleModule()).build();
    vehicle = appComponent.provideVehicle();

    ((AppInstance) getApplicationContext()).getComponent().inject(this);
}
}
```

This code is able to build the DaggerAppComponent but once I inject the AppPreference in Mainactivity it doesn't work anymore.

What am I doing wrong in injecting the preference class??
Need help..

Comment: @SanjayBhalani the accepted answer in the link says add 'SharedPreferences sharedPreferences();' in the component, but it's not working. I can't inject the preference file.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081881/dagger-2-not-injecting-sharedpreference

Comment: Thanks for the links, but still I'm unable to understand, do you mean I need to create a subcomponent for the Sharedpreference? Won't that restrict me to overall scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mistaken a couple of concepts and annotations.

You inject an object by annotating either a field or a constructor with `@Inject`. In case of the Android activities you can only use the field method. So your `MainActivity.class` should look more like this:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    SharedPreference preference;

    @Inject
    Vehicle vehicle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Inject dependencies into MainActivity
        ((AppInstance) getApplicationContext()).getComponent().inject(this);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You also don't need to use the `@Inject` annotation in your AppPreferences module as you are *providing* the dependency, not *injecting* there.

Speaking of providing, methods annotated with `@Provides` will be invoked whenever their return type is to be inject. If there are multiple provider methods with the same return type, you have to distinguish them using the `@Named` annotation or a custom qualifier. You have multiple provider methods that return `String` in your `AppPreferences` module, however I don't think they are correctly marked as provider, they seem more like a couple of operation on the `SharedPreferences` object. After cleaning up you should be left with this module:

```java
@Module
public class AppPreference {
    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    public AppPreference(Context context) {
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @ApplicationScope
    @Provides
    public SharedPreferences getPreferences() {
        return preferences;
    }
}
```

And you have to expose `SharedPreferences` in the component like you did with the `Vehicle` class:

```java
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {VehicleModule.class, AppPreference.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences();
    Vehicle vehicle();
}
```

**Edit:**
If you want some kind of wrapper for the `SharedPreferences` functionalities you can create a custom class (which is neither Dagger Component nor Module), e.g. `MyAppPreferences`:

```java
public class MyAppPreferences {
    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    public MyAppPreferences(SharedPreferences preferences) {
        this.preferences = preferences;
    }

    // put setDataPref, removeFromPref, etc. in here
}
```

And inject it like this:

```java
@Module
public class AppPreferencesModule {
    private Context context;

    public AppPreferencesModule(Context context) {
      this.context = context;
    }

    // Dagger will inject the SharedPreferences object using the providePreferences() provider
    @ApplicationScope
    @Provides
    public MyAppPreferences provideMyAppPreferences(SharedPreferences preferences) {
        return new MyAppPreferences(preferences);
    }

    @ApplicationScope
    @Provides
    private SharedPreferences providePreferences() {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {VehicleModule.class, AppPreferencesModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);

    // expose MyAppPreferences instead of SharedPreferences
    MyAppPreferences myAppPreferences();
    Vehicle vehicle();
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // inject MyAppPreferences instead of SharedPreferences
    @Inject
    MyAppPreferences myAppPreferences;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed help, I was wrong about not creating a module for AppPreference but expecting it in the activity.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the instance of SharedPreference class into the dagger Graph, given your code you can achieve this the following,

**AppModule.java**

```
@Module
class AppModule{

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   public SharedPreference providesSharedPreferences(application:Application){
      return new AppPreference(application);
   }


}
```

**AppPreferences.java**

```
public class AppPreference {
private SharedPreferences preferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor edit;

public SharedPreferences getPreferences() {
    return preferences;
}

public AppPreference(Context context) {
//        preferences       =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    preferences     =   context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);
    edit            =   preferences.edit();
}


public String setDataPref(String strKey, String strValue) {
    edit.putString(strKey, strValue);
    commitPreference();
    return strKey;
}


public String removeFromPreference(String strKey) {
    edit.remove(strKey);
    return strKey;
}

public void commitPreference()
{
    edit.commit();
}

public String getDataPref(String strKey) {
    return preferences.getString(strKey, "");
}


public boolean clear() {
    edit.clear();
    commitPreference();

    return true;
}
}
```

**AppComponent.java**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {VehicleModule.class, AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
 void inject(MainActivity activity);
 Vehicle provideVehicle();
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
class MainActivity extends Activity{

@Inject 
SharedPreference sharedPreference; //this is injected like this



}
```

Comment: If I try to inject the preference it still gives the same issue. Dagger not creating the component class.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I rectified the mistake I did, I tried out your code but the mainactivity should be injecting with AppPreference object.

Answer (score 1):

in your case i would make the AppPreference a Singleton and @Inject it where ever it is needed.

First your component should look something like this:

```
@Singleton // Constraints this component to one-per-application or unscoped bindings.
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {

        void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

        //Exposed to sub-graphs

        Context context();

        AppPreference appPreference();
        }
}
```

Then your module should look like this:

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    private final Application application;

    public ApplicationModule(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    private final Application application;

    public ApplicationModule(Application application) {
         this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Context provideApplicationContext() {
        return application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    AppPreference provideAppPreference() {
        return new AppPreference(provideApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

Then init Application Component in your Application class while holding a reference to it so you could use it later:

```
public ApplicationComponent getComponent() {
    return applicationComponent;
}

private void initializeInjector() {
        applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
                .build();
    }
```

After injecting Main Activity on onCreate() of it like this:

```
MyApplication.get(this).getComponent().inject(this);
```

You can finally use:

```
 @Inject
 AppPreference preference;
```

Comment: Why do I need to declare AppComponent inside ApplicationComponent?

Comment: I have edited the answer. I had some leftover code. Please try now.